# Django AttributeError, KeyError

Tags: python, django

This is my `views.py`

```
def new_note(request):
    form = NoteForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    . . .
    return render(request, 'newNote.html', {'note_form': NoteForm, 'registered': registered})
```

This is my `forms.py`

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        # self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate', False)
        super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        groups = StudentGroup.objects.filter(id_nauczyciela=self.user.pk)
        # print(self.user.pk)
        self.fields['id_groups'].queryset = groups

    note_name = forms.CharField(label="Note name", required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('id_groups', 'id_students', 'note_name')
```

`id_groups` is ModelChoseField

In this code i try take logged user id.

When i try use it i got error `KeyError 'user'`, when i change `self.user = kwargs.pop('user')` to `self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` i got error like this

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'

I am absolutely sure `self.user.pk` return value what i expected.

My question is How deal with this type of error?

Comment: please share your complete views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render completely ignores the form you've provided

```
return render(request, 'newNote.html', {'note_form': NoteForm, 'registered': registered})
```

Should be

```
return render(request, 'newNote.html', {'note_form': form, 'registered': registered})
```

This should solve the original key error issue you were having, the issue you found when changing the code would need different error handling

```
self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
# self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate', False)
super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if self.user is not None:
    groups = StudentGroup.objects.filter(id_nauczyciela=self.user.pk)
    # print(self.user.pk)
    self.fields['id_groups'].queryset = groups
```